# multiple awk's and if statement

Tags: awk

Below input is having two record types- its fixed width file with lines are seperated by newline. below are the sample records.

record type -41 : record length-629

record type -42 : record length-557

record type 41 and 42 are similar only 3 fields are missing. so fields which are missing i am adding it as spaces. after that i will create hive table with- TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format' --> spaces so that it will treat spaces as null values in the hive table. (sugget if there is any better way to handle this)

in record type 42, from 88th column to 113 added 26 spaces, from 114 column to 139 added 26 spaces and 165th column added 20 spaces. to make the record length 629.

i am trying to make the record type 42 which is record length as 557 adding spaces making the record length as 629 equivalent to record type 41. so that i can load this file to single hive table. below is the command i am using giving errors. can we improve this command to make the record type of 42 length with record type 41. this is fixed length file.

```
while read line
do
awk '
          $2 == "1" {
             echo $line >> test_pre.dat
             echo "record type: 41";
          }
          $2 == "2" {
             awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$88="                          "$88} 1 \
                            {$114="                          "$114} 1 \
                            {$116="                    "$116} 1'  test.dat >> test_pre.dat
             echo "record type: 42";
         }'
done
```

**INPUT:**

`41310410768228735         354447062622381 0012167121812       110012167121812           110017402445978                                                                                   06CCF005  61stas-att1.fsabcgroup0-010.ch1il01cvt.ch1il.uvp.els-an.abc.com   60000530400000002998F100F11000000000000000000000000150110192928150110192941150110192949000000080FFFFFFF00000000000000001B702A7C        0000000000000000        FFFFFFFF00                                                                abc:+12167121812@one.abc.com;user=phone                         abc:+17402445978@one.abc.com;user=phone                         000100`

`42310410755337373         354447061570839 0013133038111       110013133201177                                     06CCF005  61stas-att1.fsabcgroup0-005.ch1il01cvt.ch1il.uvp.els-an.abc.com   600004C150000000ADE5C100F11000000000000000100000000150110192815150110192822150110192950000000580000000000000000000000001B702BC9        0000000000000000        FFFFFFFF00                                                                abc:+13133201177;oli=63@abcgroup0-001-dtrtmiapca0.cl1oh.uvp.els-tel:+13133038111;npdi                                           000100`

**OUTPUT:**

`41310410768228735         354447062622381 0012167121812       110012167121812                                     110017402445978                                                                                                                                 06CCF005  61stas-att1.fsabcgroup0-010.ch1il01cvt.ch1il.uvp.els-an.abc.com   60000530400000002998F100F11000000000000000000000000150110192928150110192941150110192949000000080FFFFFFF00000000000000001B702A7C        0000000000000000        FFFFFFFF00                                                                abc:+12167121812@one.abc.com;user=phone                         abc:+17402445978@one.abc.com;user=phone                         000100`

`42310410755337373         354447061570839 0013133038111       110013133201177                                                                                         0                    6CCF005  61stas-att1.fsabcgroup0-005.ch1il01cvt.ch1il.uvp.els-an.abc.com   600004C150000000ADE5C100F11000000000000000100000000150110192815150110192822150110192950000000580000000000000000000000001B702BC9        0000000000000000        FFFFFFFF00                                                                abc:+13133201177;oli=63@abcgroup0-001-dtrtmiapca0.cl1oh.uvp.els-tel:+13133038111;npdi                                           000100`

Comment: For multiple lines of code, don't use backticks. Just put a 4 spaces in front of each line (highlight the code and use the <> code button at the top. Is your Input/Output 3 records or is it multiple? When I look at your source for this question Input/Output is 3 lines and wrapped to look like many to fit the space of the question.

Comment: input/output is having sample record one record.

Comment: How are 2 records(type 41 and 42) stored in input file? Are they just separated by a blank line? Also, will it be okay if space is added anywhere in record type 42 so that its length becomes equal to length of record type 41?

Comment: sameerkn, i have updated my question.

Comment: Since you have fixed width's why don't you just count characters and use `sed` to add the spaces at the fields you want to increase? e.g. Sum up the size of the fields up through the end of Field 41, let say that's 450 then using `sed` increase the size by 26 spaces: `sed 's/\(^[^ ]\{450\}\)\(.*$\)/\1                          \2/g'`

Answer (score 1):

1. a shell `while` loop requires the `do` and `done` keywords
2. in awk `$2` is the value of the 2nd **field**, not the 2nd character.
3. you have shell commands and shell variables in your awk script.

Basically, a mess. Try this

```
awk '
    /^.1/ {
        print > "test_pre.dat"
        print NR ": record type: 41"
    }
    /^.2/ {
        printf("%s%-143s%s\n", substr($0, 1,114), "0", substr($0,114)) > "test_pre.dat"
        print NR ": record type: 42"
    }
' test.dat
```

Not hardcoding the output file: pass in the filename as an awk variable using `-v`

```
awk -v output_file="$outfile" '
    /^.1/ {
        print > output_file
...
' "$infile"
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn :) , its working. I got the template so i can change this according to my requirement.

Comment: Hi Glenn, instead of hard coding filename( like -test_pre.dat) in the awk command is there is a way to use shell variables? if i want to run the same script for multiple files.